add multiple blazor components to dependency injection
Pretty new to Blazor and asp.net core as well.
I am reading through asp.net documentation dependency injection.
I am able to register an initial component MyCounter.razor file and import it into my ui framework.
   app.MapRazorComponents<Prodigy.Dashboards.Components.Chart>()
   .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
   app.MapRazorComponents<Prodigy.Dashboards.Components.Counter>()
   .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();```


```services.AddServerSideBlazor(options =>
{
   options.RootComponents.RegisterCustomElement<Counter>("my-counter");
   options.RootComponents.RegisterCustomElement<Chart>("my-chart");
});```

I have the ability to see counter in as 

<my-counter></my-counter>

When i go to use 

```<my-chart></my-chart>```
// That is unavailable and errors out in vscode and chrome.  

I haven't found all of the documentation on blazor to this point that.  But what i am trying to figure out if this is limited to one razor component or if this is something that i can add multiple components to? 


I am looking for access to both **Chart** and **Counter** componets.  But I want to use them separately not looking to have a parent child relationship with them.  


You only add the root component to MapRazorComponents.  Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-9.0

Thank for teh link @MrCakaShaunCurtis

The MapRazorComponents<TRootComponent> is used to specify the default root component, like this:
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();


<my-counter></my-counter>
<my-chart></my-chart>

I am looking for access to both Chart and Counter componets.
But I want to use them separately not looking to have a parent child
relationship with them.

Since you are using AddInteractiveServerRenderMode, I assume you are creating a Blazor Server application using the "Blazor Web App" Template and select the "Blazor" interactive render mode. And, from your description, it seems that you want to create custom elements for the Chart and Counter razor components and displays them using <my-counter> and <my-chart>. In this scenario, we can use the RegisterCustomElement to register the custom elements:
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor(options =>
{
    options.RootComponents.RegisterCustomElement<Counter>("my-counter");
    options.RootComponents.RegisterCustomElement<Weather>("my-weather");
});

Then the output as below:

Note: In the Home page, we are setting the render mode as InteractiveServer.
More detail information about custom elements in Blazor, see Blazor custom elements.
